# IntelliJ IDEA 14 does not recognise Python built-in types when using interpreter in virtualenv

Tags: python, intellij-idea, virtualenv, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14 on OSX for a Python project that uses a virtual environment. The program runs fine both in the terminal and using the run command inside IDEA, but it is not recognising Python built in types and functions.

[image: IDEA is not recognising Python built in types and functions]

I created the virtual environment and added it to my Project Structure following the steps below, which according to posts I read, should work, but I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

1. Added Python in `venv` as the Project SDK.

[image: Added Python in <code>venv</code> as the Project SDK]

2. Added Python in `venv` as Python interpreter in Modules.

[image: Added Python in <code>venv</code> as Python interpreter in Modules.]

3. Added Python in `venv` as the Python interpreter in Facets.

[image: Added Python in <code>venv</code> as the Python interpreter in Facets.]

4. Ensured that the appropriate Python interpreter is the selected SDK.

[image: Ensured that the appropriate Python interpreter is the selected SDK.]

5. These are the global libraries.

[image: These are the global libraries]

**[Update]**

Following one of the comments below, I recreated the virtual environment from scratch. The built-in types for Python are now recognised, but the libraries in the venv folder are not.

[image: Error importing modules.]

[image: Modules.]

Comment: This is probably more [JetBrains support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/) query than SO question. Presumably it's related to whatever is different under-the-hood between IntelliJ and PyCharm.

Comment: If you have a Python module with a Python interpreter, you don't need to add a Python facet to it as well. Please try removing the facet.

Comment: @yole, just tried that and restarted IDEA. Code still runs fine, but unfortunately it does not solve the issue with the Python built in types being unrecognised.

Comment: If you use Goto File and enter the \_\_builtin\_\_.py file name, what happens?

Comment: @yole, just tried that and nothing shows up.

Comment: Could you please try to delete and recreate your Python interpreter?

Comment: Ok. So I recreated the virtual environment and repeated all the steps above. At that point the built in types show up again, but when importing the modules in the venv (which I reinstalled using pip), it still showed me an error. I had to right click on one of the imports and select the option to install the module and that seemed to update the index. I don't know what the difference was, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: I spoke too soon. After a bit IntelliJ failed to recognise the libraries again.

Comment: Did you ever get to resolve this?

Comment: @Martin, nope. I haven't revisited the project either, so I don't know if JetBrains fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the **Python 2.7.x interpreter library** in the dependencies of your python module. Having the python SDK is not enough.

Comment: This work, just restart your Intellij after and it should pick up the builtin python modules/code.

Comment: Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Having just solved this here are some notes for others.  My problem was that `import sys` carried a red squiggle (all of a sudden).  The issue was the path for the project interpreter settings (search for "interpreter" in prefs).  Currently using OSX+PIPENV, should translate for VENV. The path is `/where/your/venv/is/located/bin/python3.6` where `python3.6` matches my version, the file is an alias.  The approach has worked for years, (AFIK) requires the binary installed on OS.  Helper command in PIPENV `pipenv --venv` for the base location. HTH, JB sux at support.